# using document.scrollTo a named element in next.js results in an document undefined error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an object that is used to to keep track of errors in a long form.

If you try to click on the submit button, and there is an error, I want to be able to scroll to that error by name.

I considered useRef, but each of these inputs are in a deep component structure, and it would need quite a lot of useRef's to be able to jump to them (and a significant rewrite of the inputs component library).

So, I figured I would just go with a simple pure javascript way:

```
function onClick(){
      const errorInputName = Object.keys(errors)[0];
      document
          .getElementsByName(errorInputName)[0]
          .scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```

The trouble is with Next.js document isn't always defined since it could run on the server side.

There seem to be plenty of ways to detect when document isn't available, but how can a force this one piece to run on the client side (even if a small delay is required).

Comment: Are you referring to `export const ISCLIENT = typeof window !== "undefined";`? Or are you asking for how to call the onClick function on the Client side?

Comment: Where is `onClick` being used? Doesn't it get triggered by an action on the client? What makes you think that'll run on the server?

Comment: It is on a form submit button @juliomalves. The error only happened when I restarted the server on the first page load, and document being undefined seems like a server error.

Comment: @SILENT, I don't have the code you mentioned, and yep, just how to call it on the client side.

Comment: @RobKohr You check to see if you're on the client using `typeof window !== "undefined"`. However, I don't understand your problem. Why are you saying the onClick issue is a server side issue? How is it even being called within the server?